# Only First Track Played on iPhone gets updated to iTunes Playlist

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, itunes-match, smart-playlist

I've searched and found issues similar to mine, but not exact.

I've got an iPhone 5 running iOS 7.1.
I've got two Macs:

- Work: Macbook Pro running 10.9.2 with iTunes 11.1.5
- Home: iMac also running 10.9.2 with iTunes 11.1.5

I pay for an iTunes match subscription. Phone and work computers have a combination of downloaded locally playing songs and ones played/streamed from the iTunes Match cloud. Not sure if that is relevant or not.

When I play songs on my iPhone, only the first one played gets an updated play count. I've got a Smart Playlist called, "Recently Played" and that only reflects the first played song on the iPhone as well.

The Smart Playist is just the 4 following rules:

- Last Played in the last 2 weeks
- Media Kind is not Podcast
- Media Kind is not Movie
- Media Kind is not TV Show

Any idea how to further diagnose why my iPhone is not reflecting more than the first played song during a session and/or how to fix?

I have tried rebooting and restoring the iPhone.

Comment: So is the problem with the smart playlist, or is it more specifically that none of your Play Counts get updated except the first song you play after a sync? It might be useful to try the app CloudScrob not for its last.fm scrobbling, but because it displays a preview list of songs played (tracked via Play Counts I assume). Could be helpful in diagnosis.